# Find out the number of solutions to the equation- $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 25$ under certain constraints

Tags: combinatorics

How many solutions are there to the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 25$ where each $x_i$ is a non-negative integer, $3 \leq x_1 \leq 10, \ 2 \leq x_2 \leq 7$ and $x_3 \geq 5$

I have been able to do all my counting problems but this one. I can not find an equation for max number per variety.

I know that I will subtract the min for each $x$ from the total, but I can not do $\begin{pmatrix} 15 \\ 6\end{pmatrix}$ cause that would not factor in the max per variety.

What is the equation I would use for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The generating function would be

$$(x^3+x^4+...+x^{10})(x^2+x^3+...+x^7)(x^5+x^6+...)(1+x+x^2+...)^3$$

Simplify,
$$x^{10}(1-x^8)(1-x^6)({1\over 1-x})^6$$

Now we are finding the coefficient of $x^{25}$ of the above, which is same as  $x^{15}$ in

$$(1-x^8)(1-x^6)({1\over 1-x})^6=(1-x^8-x^6+x^{14})({1\over 1-x})^6$$

So the coefficient of $x^{15}$ is

(coefficient of $x^{15}$ in $({1\over 1-x})^6$)$-$(coefficient of $x^{7}$ in $({1\over 1-x})^6$)$-$(coefficient of $x^{9}$ in $({1\over 1-x})^6$)$+$(coefficient of $x^{1}$ in $({1\over 1-x})^6$)

Which is basically

$${15+6-1\choose6-1}-{7+6-1\choose6-1}-{9+6-1\choose6-1}+{1+6-1\choose6-1}$$

Comment: I get $\binom{20}{5}-\color{#C00000}{\binom{14}{5}}-\binom{12}{5}+\binom{6}{5}$. I think you want to be looking at the coefficient of $x^9$ instead of $x^8$.

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake calculating $15-6$, will fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer will be the coefficient of $x^{25}$ from the below expression-

$$(x^3+x^4+ \dots+x^{10})(x^2+x^3+ \dots+x^7)(x^5+x^6+ \dots+x^{20})(x^0+x^1+ \dots+x^{15})(x^0+x^1+ \dots+x^{15})(x^0+x^1+ \dots+x^{15}).$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $y_1=x_1-3, \;y_2=x_2-2, \;y_3=x_3-5$, and $y_i=x_i$ for $4\le i\le 6$.

Then $y_1+\cdots+y_6=15$ with $y_1\le7$ and $y_2\le5$;

so if S is the set of solutions in nonnegative integers without restrictions,

$A_1$ is the set of solutions with $y_1\ge8$, and $A_2$ is the set of solutions with $y_2\ge6$,

$\displaystyle |S|-|A_1|-|A_2|+|A_1\cap A_2|=\binom{20}{5}-\binom{12}{5}-\binom{14}{5}+\binom{6}{5}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Try to find out the coefficient of $x^{25}$ from the below expression-

$$(x^3+x^4+ \dots+x^{10})(x^2+x^3+ \dots+x^7)(x^5+x^6+ \dots+x^{20})(1+x+\dots+x^{15})^3.$$

That will be your answer.

Comment: I think you need another three $({1\over 1-x})$ in your generating function.

Comment: Thanks. Yes that was a major slip. I forgot to check that there are more variables.