# Solution verification: number of solutions to the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 25$

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

**Problem statement**

I'm asked to find the number of solutions to the equation  $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 25$ (where each $x_i$ is non-negative for $i \in [1, 6] $) subject to the constraint that $3 \leq x_1 \leq 10$.

**Approach**

First, I consider bounding from below with $x_1 \geq 3$:

Let $x_1' = x_1 - 3$ such that $x_1' \geq 0$. Rearranging, $x_1 = x_1'+3$:

New equation:

$x_1' + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 22$

Using the formula for combinations over multisets, we find that there are ${{27}\choose{5}}$ solutions.

We also need $x_1$ to be bounded from above by $10$, and I approached this bit by doing negation. So I'll consider the cases where $x_1 \geq 11$ and subtract them from the cases where $x_1\geq 3$ to trap $x_1$ between $3$ and $10$.

Using the same logic as above, I get that there are ${{19}\choose{5}}$ solutions for $x_1 \geq 11$.

Finally, there are ${{27}\choose{5}} - {{19}\choose{5}}$ solutions in total.

**Questions/concerns**

Did I overcount and/or use a wrong approach here? Did I properly take care of the overlapping cases?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: All right, thank you!

Comment: You can always double check the result using generating functions approach, e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1559281/find-out-the-number-of-solutions-to-the-equation-x-1-x-2-x-3-x-4-x-5?rq=1